# Using AWS Cognito Hosted UI (Code Grant) what do I do with the token once it is verified? Subsequent API Calls do not have the token

Tags: amazon-web-services, oauth-2.0, token, amazon-cognito

MY goal is to setup the Cognito Hosted UI to validate users after login. I have followed the steps laid out in the OAuth2 blog here: https://developer.okta.com/blog/2018/04/10/oauth-authorization-code-grant-type

My steps are as follows.

1. User logs into the AWS provided login screen.
2. It redirects to my website and I pull down the authorization code in Angular.
3. I send the code as part of my headers to the backend Nodejs
4. I use the code to get a token and then validate the token

This stream works but then what? I want to validate the AWS token for each API call but I have no idea how to access the token.

I am guessing that I am either missing the point of this procedure or that the token is somewhere I am unaware of.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Usually you have your own UI that redirects to Cognito to authenticate, after which the UI sends the access token to the API on every request.

All of the code samples on my [Quick Start Page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) work like this and use Cognito.

If it helps, this is what the [OAuth Technical Messages](https://authguidance.com/2017/09/26/basicspa-oauthworkflow/) look like. Feel free to ask any follow up questions